# What does it mean mean by "Expected a statement" in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, compiler-errors

I have entered an if else code in C++ in visual studio and it shows that a statement is expected at Else and Else if

My code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{
float marks, result;
cout << "Enter your Marks:";
cin >> marks;
if(marks>=50 && marks <= 100);
{
    cout << "Passed";
}
else if (marks < 50 && marks>=0);
{
    cout << "The grade is F ";
}
else
{
    cout << "Enter marks correctly";
}
}

output is


Enter your marks:97
passedenter marks correctly
```

both statements in if and in else are printed out why ??

Comment: Please include the full error message. In which line is the error?

Comment: `if(marks>=50 && marks <= 100);` after if there should be a statement but you put a `;` voting to close as typo

Comment: @user463035818 - `;` *is* a statement :P

Comment: @StoryTeller But will cause problem with the `else` later. So it's still to blame... :)

Comment: @StoryTeller meh I knew it was wrong. One day I will read the books from chapter one, but until that I will make mistakes like that :P

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You say you get build errors, and you say that the code runs but give unexpected results. It can't be both: You *either* get build errors which means there will be no executable to run; Or you *don't* get build errors and the program runs (with possible unexpected results).

Comment: its a matter of style, but for me this is just another good reason to put the `{` in the same line. It is common to have lines ending with `);` but a line ending with `{;` would not cause that error and `;{` looks uncommon enough to be spotted easily

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: even more offtopic: Am I the only one who wonders why there are so many sad smilies in correct syntax and so little happy ones?

Comment: @user463035818 It's because you don't parse `;}` as the happy face it is.

Comment: @user463035818 `goto happy_place; /* .... */ happy_place :}`

Comment: @user463035818 Or `<=` :)

Comment: @StoryTeller considering that's where all local objects die, this has quite a grim sound to it.

Comment: @Quentin - Death is an important part of life. Can't have RAII without it

Comment: @StoryTeller now that's a killer epitaph! (heh, *killer*)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that here

```
if(marks>=50 && marks <= 100);
```

You have that `;` which shouldn't be there. Due to that, the `;` is the body of the `if` statement. It means "do nothing". As a result, the following

```
{
    cout << "Passed";
}
```

...has nothing to do with the `if` statement and will always be executed. After that is this:

```
else if (marks < 50 && marks>=0);
```

Same problem here, but the `else` can't compile, because there was no `if` before it. Remember, the block before the `else` is mistakenly not part of the `if`. Instead, what you want is this:

```
if(marks>=50 && marks <= 100)
{
    cout << "Passed";
}
else if (marks < 50 && marks>=0)
{
    cout << "The grade is F ";
}
else
{
    cout << "Enter marks correctly";
}
```